# Trying to run "pygame.examples.midi.main" but get a SyntaxError

Tags: python, syntax, pygame, midi

This is my source code:

import pygame

pygame.examples.midi.main(mode=’output’, device_id=None) -> None

I already installed pygame with no errors.  Obviously there's something wrong with the syntax (as the error message says "invalid syntax") but after searching through the pygame docs I couldn't find any info on how to run these examples.

This is the link which explains the proper syntax: http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/examples.html#pygame.examples.midi.main

Thanks in advance

Comment: I tried taking out the "-> None" affixed to the end and I still get a syntax error.

Comment: Oh and I'm using Python 2.7 x64, pygame 2.5.3 x64 (prerelease) and pyscripter x64.  All on windows 7 x64.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is with `-> None`.

That's not part of Python syntax. It's part of the documentation, just to show you what the return value of that function is. Remove that from your code and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

I typed your program into an IDLE shell (without the ->None)

The first time it said the module had no attribute 'examples'

So I restarted the shell and instead I used the lines:

```
import pygame.examples.midi
pygame.examples.midi.main(mode='output',device_id=None)
```

and it worked fine (popped up a playable keyboard).